# SQL Selects on subsets

Tags: sql, subset

I need to check if a row exists in a database; however, I am trying to find the way to do this that offers the best performance. This is best summarised with an example.

Let's assume I have the following table:

```
dbo.Person(
FirstName varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50),
Company varchar(50)
)
```

Assume this table has millions of rows, however ONLY the column `Company` has an index.

I want to find out if a particular combination of `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Company` exists. I know I can do this:

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from dbo.Person where FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName and Company = @Company)
Begin
....
End
```

However, unless I'm mistaken, that will do a full table scan.

What I'd really like it to do is a query where it utilises the index.  With the table above, I know that the following query will have great performance, since it uses the index:

```
Select * from dbo.Person where Company = @Company
```

Is there anyway to make the search only on that subset of data? e.g. something like this:

```
select * from (
  Select * from dbo.Person where Company = @Company
)
where FirstName = @FirstName and LastName = @LastName
```

That way, it would only be doing a table scan on a much narrower collection of data.

I know the query above won't work, but is there a query that would?

Oh, and I am unable to create temporary tables, as the user will only have read access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF EXISTS( ...)` is the fastest form. The optimiser will use an available index to satisfy the filter condition if it calculates the index will be faster.  `IF EXISTS` will quit as soon as a row is found.

Make sure your statistics are up to date...

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much.

Out of curiosity, what are the tags used to make parts of my questions into code form, as you have done above?

Many thanks

Comment: @Adam: just put 4 spaces to your code.  or highlight all your code, then press the 101010 icon(next double quote icon (next to earth icon))

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this is valid SQL:

```
select *
from (select * from dbo.Person where Company = @Company) t
where t.FirstName = @FirstName and t.LastName = @LastName
```

And only differs from your query by an alias.  The `IF EXISTS` will be faster as Mitch says in his post.

You can use the query analyzer to find out what the optimizer will decide to do.